# FullCalendar won't load events - fail to parse JSON

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I had a previous version of fullCalendar and it was working perfectly, the code for it is below:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events:
      {
        url: '/modules/ajax/ajax_handler.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          action: 'getBookingEventInfo'
        },
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        },
        failure: function() {
          alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        },
      },
      header:
      {
        center: 'month,agendaWeek,list'
      },
      minTime: '9:00:00',
      maxTime: '23:00:00',
      allDaySlot: false,
      aspectRatio: 2.5
    });
```

But I have just upgraded to v5 and have attempted to get the events through the same method and i get a response of 0 which implies the php query didn't work but it is working. Here is the current code:

New calendar

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          events:
          {
            url: '/modules/ajax/ajax_handler.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
              action: 'getBookingEventInfo'
            },
            failure: function() {
              alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
          },
          header:
          {
            center: 'month,agendaWeek,list'
          },
          minTime: '9:00:00',
          maxTime: '23:00:00',
          allDaySlot: false,
          aspectRatio: 2.5
        });
        calendar.render();
      });
```

PHP:

```
function getBookingEventInfo($connection, $premisesCode) {
  $dates = array();
  $query = "SELECT reservation_date, count(*), r.start_time, r.end_time FROM bookings b JOIN reservation_time_data r ON r.id = b.reservation_time
  WHERE premises_code = ? AND reservation_processed NOT IN ('no-show', 'removed') GROUP BY reservation_date";

  if($stmt = $connection->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $premisesCode);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($date, $count, $startTime, $endTime);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
      $dates[] = array(
        "title" => $count." reservations.",
        "start" => formatDate($date, 14)." ".$startTime,
        "end" => formatDate($date, 14)." ".$endTime,
        "url" => "/rapido/view-reservation-queue/".formatDate($date, 14)
      );
    }
    $stmt->close();
  }
  return json_encode($dates);
}
```

Comment: Start by checking what the actual response is, using your browser dev tools, network panel.

Comment: It gets a response of 200 from the ajax handler. Also it doesn't work when i try and manually hard code the events

Comment: Some things have changed - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/events-json-feed. Check carefully the names of the parameters you can set in the events config (e.g. you can't use `data` anymore...it's changed). Did you read this documentation yet after you upgraded (or, preferably... _before_ you upgraded)?

Comment: @ADyson Ill read it now, i didn't think things would change. Thank you

Comment: Well it's a major upgrade so it's reasonable to assume that things _might_ have changed. Therefore when you encounter a problem after the upgrade the first logical step should be to check the documentation to see whether that's the case :-)